# Error:Kotlin:Out-projected type 'JComboBox<*>' prohibits the use of '@BeanProperty public open fun setModel(p0: ComboBoxModel<E!>!)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and am translating some Java code to it.

The code I came up with is:

```
val comboBox: JComboBox<*> = JComboBox<Any?>()
        comboBox.font = Font("苹方", Font.PLAIN, 15)
        comboBox.setModel(DefaultComboBoxModel<Any?>(s))   /*
error:Out-projected type 'JComboBox<*>' prohibits the use of '@BeanProperty public open fun setModel(p0: ComboBoxModel<E!>!): Unit defined in javax.swing.JComboBox'
*/
       comboBox.setBounds(341, 73, 170, 28)
        panel.add(comboBox)
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error:Kotlin:Out-projected type 'JComboBox<*>' prohibits the use of '@BeanProperty public open fun setModel(p0: ComboBoxModel<E!>!)
```

What am I doing wrong?

For completeness this is my original java code:

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setFont(new Font("苹方", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(s));
        comboBox.setBounds(341, 73, 170, 28);
        panel.add(comboBox);
```

Answer (score 1):

the previous code:

```
val comboBox: JComboBox<*> = JComboBox<Any?>()
```

should be changed to:

```
val comboBox = JComboBox<Any?>()
```